# How to specify the association with factory_bot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

For example I have two models a user and a post. A post belongs_to a user and a user has many posts

```
#spec/factories/post.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    user
    body Faker::Movie.quote
    posted_at "2018-04-03 13:33:05"
  end
end

#spec/factories/user.rb
FactoryBot.define do 
  factory :user do 
    first_name 'Jake'
  end
end
```

Using Rspec in a test I want to do this:

```
user = create(:user, first_name: 'Barry') #id 1
post = create(:post, user: user)
```

I would expect that the user_id of post to be 1 however it is creating another user prior and the user_id is 2.

How can you specify the association when you are creating the object with factory_bot / factory_girl?

Comment: What does `post.user.inspect` and `User.all` return after you make the post?

Comment: post.user is User

Comment: and User.all is equal two users

Comment: Can you post your complete spec? Do you have any kind of authentication involved? If you have to login to run the spec, that could be the source of the other user.

Comment: Also, what the `first_names` in the records? Are they both `Jake`?

Comment: no its just that as a plain spec

Comment: to your second question first one has a first name of 'barry' and the second one has a first name of 'jake'

Comment: factory :post do      here post is pointing the actual model or this is created here ? & if this one is model & located within a module how can we locate it ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### Update Dec 2023

The FactoryBot association can be specified in both explicit and implicit associations. At least from version factory_bot-6.2.0

#### Original response

You should use `explicit` associations instead of `implicit` ones:

```
#spec/factories/post.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    association :user    # <<<--- here the change
    body Faker::Movie.quote
    posted_at "2018-04-03 13:33:05"
  end
end

#spec/factories/user.rb
FactoryBot.define do 
  factory :user do 
    first_name 'Jake'
  end
end
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: Are there more arguments on why you should use explicit associations instead of implicit ones?

Comment: Using explicit associations is the only way to be able to override the attributes of the associated object. When the association is implicit, FactoryBot will create an associated object on which you don't have control of its attributes (it will automatically create an associated object based on the factory for that object).
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#overriding-attributes

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use `#trait` method within the parent.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    user nil
    body Faker::Movie.quote
    posted_at "2018-04-03 13:33:05"
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do 
  factory :user do 
    first_name 'Jake'
  end

  trait :with_post do
    after(:create) do |user|
      create(:post, user_id: user.id)
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.create(:user, :with_post)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here we have another solution in case your association name and factory name is different then you can follow below syntax.

```
#spec/factories/post.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    association :author, factory: :user
    body Faker::Movie.quote
    posted_at "2018-04-03 13:33:05"
  end
end
```

in case your factory name is author and model name is user then you can use above syntax